# What is the best algorithm to stop the winning function of connect four to return true again?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

my winning function works well, but let's say there's four circles in a line and the line got 10 columns when I add the 5th circle the winning function return true again. is there a way to mark the already won circles and how?

here's the code:

```
function horizontalWin(row, col) {
    var playervalue = avatar[turn];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var slot = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells[i].innerHTML;
        if (slot == playervalue) {
            count++;
            if (count >=4) {return true;}
        }
        else {count = 0}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So in your version, the game doesn't stop once a win is reached? Play continues? I guess you could save the X/Y coordinates in an array, and check them

Comment: Why does the game continue when there's already a winner?

Comment: no I don't want to stop the game, I want to continue with a score but it returns true because the count is greater than four. I want when there's 8 circles score = 2. but here 4= 1 and 5 = 2 and 6 = 3 ...

Comment: @CertainPerformance I already tried saving the class of the columns already won in an array but it didn't work