# How to make this function works properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I posted before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156108/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-stop-the-winning-function-of-connect-four-to-retur) but I didn't make it clear and I didn't try but now I tried and it didn't work. I'm making a connect four game with score and it doesn't end when someone connect 4 colors. the grid has more than 8 columns, when someone connect four colors the win func returns true but when I add the 5th it returns true too even if it's not consecutive. I think seeing the code is easier to understand:

```
function horizontalWin(row, col) {
    var no = [];
    var playervalue = avatar[turn];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var slot = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells[i].innerHTML;
        var slo = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells[i].getAttribute("class");
        if (slot == playervalue && no.includes(slo)==false) {
            count++;
            no.push(slo);
            if (count >=4) {return true;}
        }
        else {count = 0; no = [];}
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want when there is 4 connected colors --> score = 1, 8 --> score = 2. but now 4-->1, 5-->2, 6-->3 ....

Comment: *"...but when I add the 5th it returns true too..."* Are you trying to make five-in-a-row not a win? (It typically is a win in Connect4.)

Comment: I want to make it just four

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make five-in-a-row not a win (that is, only **exactly* four-in-a-row is a win), you need to not stop when you get to `count == 4` (you currently stop because you do `return true`).

See `***` comments for the logic change, and a few other suggestions:

```
function horizontalWin(row, col) {
    var no = [];
    var playervalue = avatar[turn];
    var count = 0;
    // *** There's no reason to constantly go back to the DOM for this collection
    var cells = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];
        var slot = cell.innerHTML;
        var slo = cell.className;
        if (slot == playervalue && !no.includes(slo)) { // *** Avoid === true and === false
            count++;
            no.push(slo);
            // *** No return here, so we continue and check for five in a row
        } else {
            // *** If they've already won, we can stop now
            if (count === 4) {
                break;
            }
            count = 0;
            no = [];
        }
    }
    return count === 4; // *** Only a win if exactly four
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but my goal is to make 8 in a row two win and not making 5 and 6 and 7 a win just because the count is 4. and if there is 4 in a row --> that's a win--> not count them anymore.

Comment: @Moswers - Then change both `count === 4` comparisons above to `count === 4 || count === 8` (or `count && count % 4 === 0`).

Comment: thanks a lot man, there are some little problems but I can fix them. thanks for showing me how to start.